# Programmed I/O vs DMA

Tags: memory, file-io, cpu, cpu-architecture

I was wondering if maximum bandwidth can differ in Programmed I/O versus DMA. My confusion comes from the following

If we have only one bus for cpu, memory and I/O device and we are using Programmed I/O, does the data goes directly from I/O to memory when we are reading something or it goes to CPU first then to memory. Meaning if we can transfer 10 bytes per transfer and each transfer takes 20 miliseconds, does that mean that with Programmed I/O max bandwith per second is

10 * 20 * 10^-9 ?

or do I need to consider the fact that it goes to CPU first and then from CPU tot memory ?

Comment: The bigger difference is in CPU load, see my answer.  Also, 10 byte chunks?  It's going to be a power of 2, like 16 bytes.  And 20 ms per transfer?  Does your CPU run at 1kHz?  20 ms is 32 million DRAM clock cycles, for 1600MHz RAM.  Of course, modern x86 CPUs have split busses for RAM vs. device I/O, because they have the memory controller on-chip.  See the diagram on http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/08/the-many-tricks-intel-skylake-uses-to-go-faster-and-use-less-power/ which shows the System Agent vs. memory bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a system laid out like you suggest in your question, and CPU <-> Northbridge bandwidth was the bottleneck, then yes *maybe* you could get data from an extremely high bandwidth device into RAM faster with DMA than PIO.  It sounds plausible that that could possibly happen in some systems with VERY fast devices relative to the CPU's connection to the outside world.

Of course, modern x86 systems don't even have [a Northbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)), because the memory controller is on-chip.  That doesn't invalidate the question about computer architecture, but it does render it less relevant.  IDK what other chips (like ARM) tend to do.  But since high levels of integration  are common (including SoC (System on Chip)), I wouldn't be surprised if separate Northbridges are disappearing from the non-x86 world as well.

---

The difference between PIO and DMA is mostly not about which can achieve the highest bandwidth, but which slows the system down more.  Running a copy loop more or less fully occupies a CPU core for the entire duration of the copy.  This was an even bigger deal before multi-core CPUs.

A copy loop also pollutes caches, but this can be mostly avoided with special cache-bypassing instructions.

On x86, the [`in`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IN.html) and [`out`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/OUT.html) programmed-I/O instructions can't pipeline particularly well.  They're not serializing like `CPUID`, but [they do drain the store buffer](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/coherent.htm) and aren't very friendly to out-of-order execution.  This is one reason memory-mapped I/O with regular load/store operations is preferred over `in`/`out` for PIO.  e.g. just to write a device's IO registers to initiate a DMA transfer, or for small transfers where DMA isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2):

PIO usually goes directly to the CPU. Even CISC instructions which copy from memory-to-memory still need to use an instruction slot on the CPU pipeline. The loading instruction may experience a large bus-delay also compared to RAM reads. Also factor in a loop instruction if you are copying a large amount and it's easy to see why DMA is more efficient.

Comment: So if we have PIO and we need to transfer data from disk to memory lets say. That data first goes to cpu and then goes to memory ?

Comment: Yes, the CPU pulls the value over the bus.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused, so CPU pulls value over bus to its registers/cache and then sends it to Memory ? So lets say bus can transfer 1 byte per second and we need to transfer 5 bytes from disk to ram, will it take 5 seconds or 10 ?

Comment: Depends on the hardware system, there are several different ways a PIO system can implemented. On most systems you have a status register which you would have to continuously read (poll) to wait for a ready bit, and then read the data, you could also have interrupts fired off by the hardware for when data becomes available.

Comment: To answer your originally post a little more, PIO maximum transfer speeds is the speed it takes to get a new value from hardware. It does not factor in the amount of additional time a CPU may take issuing the load instruction, or the extra time that CPU then takes writing the value back to memory, all of those things should be unpredictable from the hardwares point of view.